# Why doesn't using two <= in a conditional statement work?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm writing an easy conditional structure:

```
numero = as.integer(readline(prompt="Elige un número cualquiera: "))

if(numero < 0){
  paste0("El número", numero, "es negativo.")
} else {
  if(0 <= numero <= 100){
     paste0("El número", numero, "está entre 0 y 100.")
  } else {
     paste0("El número", numero, "es mayor que 100.")
  }
}
```

However, when running this code an error arises:

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:8:18: unexpected '<='
7: } else {
8:   if(0 <= numero <=                 ^
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not math. You need to be explicit.

Try `if(0 <= numero && numero <= 100)`

In addition, I would recommend to use the vectorised `ifelse()`

Comment: This is a single number, so you should use `&&` not `&`. Don't use `ifelse`, it would be a source of errors.

Comment: I wouldn't even use `if` and `else`. I 'd make it a factor

Comment: @dash2 it works with both `&` and `&&`.

Comment: @Sotos I have to use `if` and `else` in order to show an example of this conditional structure. I'm writing an R introductory notebook.

Comment: @AlejandroDGR it works, but it's not right. If `numero` for any reason ended up with more than one element, you'd trigger a warning, which is becoming an error in R-devel.

Comment: @dash2 Hence the use of `ifelse()` in that case

Comment: I think if you are testing a single value, you want to use functions that assume you are testing a single value, like `&&` and `if`. Otherwise you will hide your errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition within `if()` is not coded properly. In addition, to make a space between strings in a sentence in this case, `paste` is better than `paste0`.

Here is an alternative fix:

```
numero = as.integer(readline(prompt="Elige un número cualquiera: "))
if(numero < 0){
    paste("El número", numero, "es negativo.")
} else {
    if(numero >=0 & numero <= 100){
        paste("El número", numero, "está entre 0 y 100.")
    } else {
        paste("El número", numero, "es mayor que 100.")
    }
}
```

Comment: You were absolutely correct about the `paste` issue.